# Can you have both Pycharm Community and Professional installed on your computer?

Tags: pycharm

I'm upgrading to Pycharm Professional, but I do not want to uninstall the Community version. Has anyone installed both and if so run into any issues? Is it ok to install both? Or is it better to remove the Community version? What are some cons and pros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can keep both. 
They are two different applications, not different versions of the same app.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I'm running into some issues activating my Professional license so I thought maybe I had to uninstall Community version

Comment: I use both versions myself :)
kindly upvote if you find this helpful.